# Нужно сделать regex

Tags: javascript, node.js, регулярные-выражения

многоуважаемые разработчики. Хотел бы попроситься с просьбой. Я пишу скрипт для обработки большого количества никнеймов, если быть конкретным нужно проверить подходит ли никнейм под описание формы. Никнеймы такого формата - [SFMC][1] Nick_Name, вместо SFMC могут подставляться другие теги, а во втором аргументе может быть максимум 1-10. Я хотел сделать регулярное выражение с помощью которого бы проверялась валидность ника, но не сумел, для меня это очень больная тема которую я никак не могу осознать. Был бы благодарен, если бы написали небольшой regex который бы мог проверить валидность этого ника.

Comment: Так покажите Ваши попытки

Comment: И примеры тоже выложите. Входные данные и что в итоге хотите получить.

Comment: @DiD
попытки к сожалению не смогу показать, ибо я их уже стер и в них особо ничего стоющего не было.
Я буду проверять через regex.test(text) и хочу видеть результат в виде boolean, примеры тоже с ним будут.

``[LVMPD][2] Sava_Shadow -> true
[LVMPD] [5] L.Hamel -> true
[LSMC] [5]Deivid_Brown -> true
[LSMC] Deivid_Brown -> false
[5] [LSMC] -> false``

В первых скобках находятся теги, их будет много. Около 20, я их сам смогу поставить через |

Comment: `/^\[\w+\]\[\d\] .+$/.test(nickname)`

Comment: @nörbörnën спасибо большое работает.

Answer (score 0):

Благодаря комментарию [@nörbörnën](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1350211/%d0%9d%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-regex/1350254#comment2393641_1350211), так работает:

```
/^\[\w+\]\[\d\] .+$/.test(nickname)
```

Comment: @nörbörnën не слишком ли сильно вы урезали ответ?